# Find reoccuring values in one column that correspond to differing values in another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns. The first column ("A") contains numbers, the second ("B") letters:

```
A B
1 a
1 a
1 a
2 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
4 e
5 f
5 g
5 g
5 h
```

Most numbers are always matched with the same letter (e.g. "1" is always matched with "a"), but some numbers are matched with different letters (e.g. "2"  is matched with "b" and "c"). I want to find the numbers that are matched with multiple letters. For the example, the result should be a vector containing "2" and "5".

---

Sample Data:

```
example <- read.table(textConnection('
A B
1 a
1 a
1 a
2 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
4 e
5 f
5 g
5 g
5 h
'), header = TRUE, colClasses=c("double", "character"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as @Paul's without the apply function

```
names(which(rowSums(table(example$A, example$B) != 0) > 1))

-output
>
[1] "2" "5"
```

Comment: This only works because the numbers in my example are consecutive. Your code doesn't actually return the numbers from column A, but the positions of those numbers in the table. If column A contained something other than numbers, or if the numbers weren't consecutive, your code wouldn't return the expected result. I had to adapt your code like this: `names(which(rowSums(table(example$A, example$B) != 0) > 1))`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks @user52445, you're totally right, `which` returns the **index** and what we want is the value of vector A. I've edited my solution per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
> distinct(example) %>% group_by(A) %>%
+   summarize(count = n()) %>%
+   filter(count > 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      A count
  <dbl> <int>
1     2     2
2     5     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, in `base R`:

```r
as.numeric(names(which(apply(table(example$A, example$B), 1, 
     \(x) sum(x == 0) != (length(x)-1)))))

#> [1] 2 5
```

Comment: Your code does not return the numbers from column A, but the positions of those numbers in the table. This is a problem when the numbers aren't consecutive or the column contains strings instead of numbers. See my comment to the answer by guasi. This works: `names(which(apply(...)))`, i.e. without `unname()`. But thank you for your help. I wouldn't have found my solution without it.

Comment: Thanks, @user52445, for your comment. You are right! I have just updated my solution accordingly.